# Time format of datetime field in .net

Tags: c#, .net, time

i have a datetime field whih is showing date time as 11/03/14 12:00 AM.How can i convert this time to 00:00 instead of 12:00 AM.

i tried

```
    DateTime.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

Comment: you mean 24 hr format? What format do you want. What is your required output

Comment: Have a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Well, you don't really need to convert the datetime value. You just need to specify the output format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it first to `DateTime`, then you could use `ToShortDateString`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("11/03/14 12:00 AM", "dd/MM/yy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx